# In a broad sense, can all the machine learning tasks be viewed as classification?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification

In a broad sense, can all the deep learning tasks be viewed as classification?

Comment: This is a very sparse question that asks almost nothing. Could you please give some context so that your question can make more sense?

Answer (score 1):

No.

It is totally reasonable to predict values that exist on a continuum (“regression”). In such a scenario, it makes no sense to assign a probability to any particular value, since every value taken by a continuous distribution has zero probability.

Further, a classical classification problem gives no sense of order among the categories. If the predictions are real numbers, then not only did a model predicting $4$ when the truth is $7$ get it wrong, but the model is more wrong than it would have been had it predicted $5$.